# Phrasing in résumé/CV

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrases

I want to list this in my résumé: In an invited talk, I explained the application of `X` technique and then demonstrated with example `A`.

My current phrasing is

> Invited talk on the application of X technique; demonstrated with
>   example A

But I am not sure if my usage of `demonstrated with` is idiomatic. Does my phrasing sound native? Please let me know if you have any better way of phrasing my experience.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct says "demonstrated *using* example A". "With" is an ambiguous word. If you use "with", it sounds that the application is offered with example A when you demonstrate it.

Use colon (:), not semicolon (;). A semicolon cannot be used with the predicate "demonstrated using example A". It needs a full sentence.

Some Google results:
*CPU Usage Demonstration using DMAC*(Atmel)

*LIN Demonstration Using PGA450Q1EVM* (Texas Instrument)

Answer (score 0):

Résumés are very condensed text.  Although they are not as condensed as headlines, they use some of the same grammatical techniques.  In other words, many shorter phrases are okay in résumés, but not in ordinary text.

The original post's example is not a complete sentence.  The subject ("I") has been left out of both clauses.  These omissions are normal in résumés.  Here is a fuller interpretation of the original example:

> [I gave an invited] talk on the application of X technique; [I] demonstrated with example A[.]

The longer version would be grammatically correct in standard writing.  As I mentioned before, it is normal to leave out "I" (and words that "I" makes necessary) when writing a résumé.  Thus, the original post's shorter version is grammatically correct **in the context of a résumé**.